# Windows 2012 DNS getting public ip instead of NIC IP

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

Win 2012 ADDC DNS

Today PCs were unable to login to domain. We transfered the ADDC to a new server a few weeks ago. After all the troubleshooting I found out that DNS is not working correctly, basically the domain name in use (ex. domain.com), refers to an actual www.domain.com which we do not control nor have access to (different company unrelated to us). Why ? I really do not know, its has been like that since 1998 and I guess my boss forgot to register the domain name or lost it long time ago. Now the problem is, DNS is registering the domain GUID with internet IP instead of server IP. How can I fix that ?

```
C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN>dcdiag /test:connectivity

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = PayrollDCServer
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\PAYROLLDCSERVER
      Starting test: Connectivity
         Although the Guid DNS name
         (81759a30-38c1-4cd3-8055-bc9ce4673ed0._msdcs.domainx.com) resolved to
         the IP address (158.xxx.x.xxx), which could not be pinged, the server                <-- that IP is the one from the domainx.com on the internet 
         name (PayrollDCServer.domainx.COM) resolved to the IP address (::1)
         and could be pinged.  Check that the IP address is registered
         correctly with the DNS server.
         Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your
         firewall settings.
         ......................... PAYROLLDCSERVER failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\PAYROLLDCSERVER
      Skipping all tests, because server PAYROLLDCSERVER is not responding to
      directory service requests.
```

**all the other test pass

When I try to open the DNS console I get "Access Denied" and cannot change anything. I already tried: net stop dns, net stop netlogon, ipconfig /flushdns, net start dns, net start netlogon.

Other info:

```
C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PayrollDCServer
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : DOMAINX.COM
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : DOMAINX.COM

Ethernet adapter Ethernet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connectio
n #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-2D-62-49
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

NIC connection shows only as "Private"

Comment: You purchase a domain name and use that.

Comment: The DCAGuid CNAME record should be aliased to the Domain Controller, which should have an A record registered for the internal ip address. The only reason I can think that this would be happening is if the A record for the DC is registered for the public ip address. Take a look at the netlogon.dns file on the DC and look for any instances of the public ip address. If you find any, replace them with the internal ip address and stop/restart the Netlogon service or reboot the DC.

Comment: I checked the netlogon.dns file and no foreign IP there. Checked the DNS files and not sure if cause I have stopped/started the service, flushdns, etc,  so many times but now the file is empty (0 kb)

The only thing I found on the netlogon file was:
_ldap._tcp.b05f9c16-0b11-4c7a-9e62-f1c59cac90df.domains._msdcs.DOMAINX.COM.

81759a30-38c1-4cd3-8055-bc9ce4673ed0._msdcs.DOMAINX.COM. PayrollDCServer.DOMAINX.COM

those 2 have different GUID, is it supposed to be like that ?

Comment: Yes, one is the domain GUID CNAME record and the other is the DSA GUID CNAME record for the Domain Controller.

Comment: There's no reason the DC should be picking up or registering the public ip address. Many organizations have inadvertently or erroneously used a public DNS name internally (split-DNS). This is not one of the symptoms of doing that. Does the DC have the public ip address configured as an additional ip address on the NIC? If so, remove it. Is the AD DNS zone Ad integrated? If so, find and delete the value in the dnsRecord attribute for the DC. If not, then edit the DNS zone file and delete the A record for the DC. Reboot the DC.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I ended up starting a new server from scratch and re create a new domain, dns,etc.
I believe it was needed at one point since the current setup was an upgrade from an upgrade from an upgrade back since Win 2000 Server !

Thanks a lot for you help and time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy fix here.  I actually have a customer in the same state.  As long as they have internet access DNS will properly resolve this to the owners domain.  Pick a new name, buy it, migrate to the new forest.

Comment: The Domain Controller should see itself as authoritative for the zone. Queries to/for that zone should be answered by the DC, even queries originating from the DC itself.

Comment: The problem is (at least in my case) not everything under the domain name resolves, thus it fwd to the internet, so stuff. Servers.unowneddomain.com breaks.  It also means you can't buy certs.

Comment: Problem for me now is that some employees are no longer able to login to domain, my domain is completely broken, internet request is really slow for them, sometimes they can access files in network, sometimes they get errors.  Thinking about starting  a new domain from scratch. How can I avoid this from happening again?